# Typedef for list parameter

Tags: c++, list, typedef

I want implement `typedef` as in example below.  However, the compiler will not run this. Is it possible implement or not? If not, is there an alternative?

```
typedef <char, int> myDefs;
map<myDefs> myMap;
```

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). In the current form, no what you're asking is not possible. It may be possible to hack it together using something obscure, but you'll get better answers if you clarify *why* you need to do something like this.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo: what he is asking is definitely possible, albeit with slightly different syntax. See my answer.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Yes, but I'd still wager it's a XY problem.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo no, it's question just for my education

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template <template <typename...> class Map>
using with_my_defs = Map<char, int>;
```

Usage:

```
with_my_defs<map> myMap;
```

[**live example on wandbox.org**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/nENxOs)

Comment: Creative and horrifying at the same time. Brilliant!

Comment: @VittorioRomeo Thank you